# Iterate over fields and print only those matching regex

Tags: regex, awk, field

I am having trouble getting this to work:

```
awk  -F ";" '{for(i=1; i < NF;i++) $i ~ /^_.*/ {print $i}}'
```

I want to iterate over all the fields (records can have 7-9) and print only those that start with an `_` except the line above gives me a syntax error at the print statement and if I omit the `{print $i}` I dont get any output.

How is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing an `if`:

```
awk  -F ";" '{for(i=1; i < NF;i++) if($i ~ /^_.*/) {print $i}}'
```

The structure of an awk program is `condition { action }` but what you have currently is all within an action block (the condition is *true* by default). Within the action block the `if` isn't implicit.

As an aside, the `.*` in the pattern is redundant; you may as well use `/^_/` to match any string starting with `_`.

**Note**: since fields are 1-indexed, likely that the right loop condition is `i <= NF`. If you are sure that the last field is unnecessary, condition `i < NF` will do the job.

Comment: Right and the `.*` in `/^_.*/` is doing nothing since it means zero or more occurrences of any character so `/^_/` alone will be true for exactly the same fields as would be true for `/^_.*/`.